# Hierarchial Tree structure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is the table 'treestuc':

```
Parent Branch BranchLevel Sequence
----------------------------------
TREE    A              1    1
TREE    B              1    2
A       C              2    1
A       D              2    2
A       E              2    3
B       F              2    1
B       G              2    2
C       Z              3    1
```

I need the output as follows:

```
A     1.1
B     1.2 
C     1.1.1 
D     1.1.2
E     1.1.3 
F     1.2.1 
G     1.2.2
Z     1.1.1.1
```

I have tried the following, but I can't get the correct output:

```
SET @len = (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM treestuc
        )

CREATE TABLE #treelevels (
    nodename VARCHAR(max),
    branchlevel VARCHAR(max)
    )

INSERT INTO #treelevels
SELECT DISTINCT parent,
    '1' AS branchlevel
FROM treestuc
WHERE parent NOT IN (
        SELECT branchname
        FROM treestuc
        )

WHILE (@len > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #treelevels
    SELECT branch AS NodeName,
        Cast(tl.branchlevel + SUBSTRING(t.branchlevel, 2, 3) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS branchlevel
    FROM treestuc AS t
    INNER JOIN #treelevels AS tl
        ON t.parent = tl.nodename

    SET @len = @len - 1
END
```

Comment: What RDBMS is are you using? If sql-server, what version?

Comment: SET @len=(SELECT Count(*) FROM   treestuc) 
CREATE TABLE #treelevels ( nodename    VARCHAR(max), branchlevel VARCHAR(max) ) 
INSERT INTO #treelevels 
SELECT DISTINCT parent,  '1' AS branchlevel 
FROM   treestuc WHERE  parent NOT IN(SELECT branchname FROM   treestuc) 
WHILE( @len > 0 ) 
  BEGIN INSERT INTO #treelevels 
      SELECT branch AS NodeName  , Cast(tl.branchlevel+SUBSTRING(t.branchlevel,2,3)  AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS branchlevel 
      FROM   treestuc AS t 
             INNER JOIN #treelevels AS tl 
                     ON t.parent = tl.nodename SET @len=@len - 1   END

Comment: Yes trying out with recursive CTE's but not able to get the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you Recurisve CTE should be something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cteTree (branch, path) AS
(
    SELECT
        branch,
        CAST('1.' + sequence as VARCHAR(20))
    FROM
        treestruc
    WHERE Parent='Tree'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        treestruc.Branch,
        cteTree.path + '.' + sequence
    FROM
        cteTree
        INNER JOIN treestruc ON
            cteTree.Branch = treestruc.Parent

)

SELECT * FROM cteTREE
```

This selects the first term with `"Tree"` as the `Parent`, then the recursive term looks for it's decendants and creates the Path using a period as a separator.

Comment: It throws out an error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "path" of recursive query "cteTree".

Comment: Try tossing a `CAST` in that first bit. I just added it. See if that makes it happy.

Comment: Can you please explain about the branch z that retrieves 1.1.1.1. How does it execute.

Comment: It starts at TREE and makes `1.1`. Then it looks at the child `C` that has a parent `A` and appends another `1` from that record's `sequence`, so we have `1.1.1`. Then in the next recursive loop it finds the `Z` is a child of `C`, so it appends it's `sequence` which is a `1` to make `1.1.1.1`